# Laravel search results paginate without direct collection

Tags: php, laravel, search

I have a search like:

```
$users = User::search($q)
               ->orderBy($sortBy, $orderBy)
               ->paginate($perPage);
```

and I can paginate results in blade with

```
{{ $users->render() }}
```

no problem.
However my SearchController continues like

```
if($request->loc){
    $users = $users->where('loc',$request->loc);
}
if($request->sz) {
    $users = $users->where('sz',$request->sz);
}
...
return view('search', compact('users'));
```

which means I cant use the {{ $users->render() }} in blade because $users doesnt have the orderBy, paginate of the collection.

How can I solve this? Thanks for answer!

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand, it might be better for you to paste the full method that you are using for the saerch. I am guessing `search()` is a scope on the `User` model?

Comment: Yes thats correct its a scopeSearch in user model 
```
public function scopeSearch($query, $q) {
        if ($q == null) return $query;
        return $query
                ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$q}%");
} 
```
The point is im getting $users directly from User:: collection but within the search Im filter the same $users for other search requests but I can only use paginate when I use the User:: collection directly and not the passed $users

Comment: How are you passing data to the collection? collection accepts a builder instance, so you should be able to pass your query. Also, you can try applying paginate before `return` incase laravel unsets pagination.

Answer (score 0):

You should not combine pagination and filtering the Collections, it can make the results flakey. If you want filtering with pagination you have to do it on the `QueryBuilder`.

For your logic you can utilize `when($condition, $clojure)` on the `QueryBuilder` that will only execute if the condition is true.

```
$users = User::search($q)
           ->orderBy($sortBy, $orderBy)
           ->when($request->loc, function ($query) use ($request) {
               $query->where('loc', $request->loc);
           })
           ->when($request->sz, function ($query) use ($request) {
               $query->where('sz', $request->sz);
           })
           ->paginate($perPage);

return view('search', compact('users'));
```